# How to display image blob from postgres to VB 6?

Tags: postgresql, vb6

I have an application written in VB6 and would like to know how I would display an image blob from postgres to VB6?

Answer (score 1):

If the image blob is in one of several standard formats (BMP, JPEG, GIF, TIFF file format) you can use WIA 2.0 for this.

Get the blob as a Byte array, create a WIA.Vector object, assign the Byte array to the Vector.BinaryData property, then you can use the Vector.Picture property to retrieve a StdPicture object you can assign to an Image or PictureBox control.

Answer (score 0):

[This code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=29004&lngWId=1) can help if the image can be loaded to a picture box. 
See the `PictureFromByteStream()` Function in Module1.bas

Comment: The linked code is hacky at best. Try [Load and save pictures to byte arrays][1] for the `IPersistStream` way. MS Access is using this when pasting images in BLOBs.

[1]: http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/index.shtml